# Applying for DS-160 B2 U.S. Visa. Surrender of Passport

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I have an interview date in March but then realised if successful I need to hand over my passport for up to 14 days.

My problem is I am going on a family holiday to Spain a week after the interview date and will need to have my passport.
My assumption is my passport won’t we back with me.

On the Embassy website it states that if an applicant’s passport cannot be released, the interviewing officer must be informed prior to commencement of the interview. You cannot tell the officer once the interview has started. My reading of that suggests there is a contingency plan but that isn’t explained.

Will they let me hand in my passport for processing after I return or will they just cancel the application and I will need to reapply.

If it’s the latter then my best plan is reschedule the date now, in that way I don’t loose my fee.

I have filled in an On-Line enquiry form on the Embassy web site, asking the question, but not holding my breath with respect to a response.

Has anyone had this problem, if you have, I would love to hear of your experiences.

Comment: Rescheduling your interview — to delay the interview until after you return from your trip — would seem to accomplish your goals to have the interview, be free to hand in your passport at the interview, and not have to pay the application fee again. Why would you hesitate to do just that?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Rescheduling does seem the obvious action, the lead time for appointments is 3 months and naturally you return to the bottom of the pile.   My hesitancy is there are snippets of information on the Visa website that suggests there is a contingency arrangement whereby if successful in obtaining a visa, you can retain your passport then hand it in later for processing.  The US Embassy sites for Saudi and Australia state this in their Q&A but not the UK site.  I have filled in a web form question to the London Embassy asking for clarification.

Comment: That's a reasonable step, But do onsider now what you might do if, after some period of time, you've received no answer to your query to the US Embassy in London.

Comment: As mentioned earlier I have a query logged with the Embassy via their Web Form.  They state that can take 3 to 5 to process with a response.   The plan then is to wait until next Tuesday 12th March which is 7 days before my Interview Date.  If nothing concrete in the way guidance has been received, Ito be on the safe side, I will reschedule

Comment: Just to update the thread.  Found a phone number that is titled ‘Visa Enquires’, rang it and my surprise someone answered.  Helpful lady said she believed it’s possible to delay handing in your passport for processing. Job done I thought and asked her to confirm this in writing.  She said they weren’t part of the Embassy staff but an agency contracted by the Embassy's to handle enquires so couldn’t give a definitive answer.  So basically they suggest possible but unofficial answers.

Comment: The problem with relying on this non-official source is that you may get to the interview and find that the Embassy official will not permit you to retain your passport. If so, you'll be on the horns of a dilemma: either give up your passport (which would mean you'd not be able to go on the family trip), or refuse to give the passport, which would (at best) act as a withdrawal of your application. I would risk this outcome **only** if I'd received an assurance **in writing** from an official source that keeping your passport would be OK. In any event, report back and let us know what happens.

Comment: Have decided that if ny next Tuesday (1 week before interview date), I haven’t a definitive answer saying I can withhold my passport, I will reschedule.   Interestingly my daughter is a lawyer working for a big international London law firm.  They have people flying around the world to the extent they have a department who handle visas and travel documents.  She has spoken them and even they aren’t sure so what chance do I have.

Comment: I think your proposed course of action is very prudent.